# Breakpoint on static properties Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, debugging, properties, visual-studio-2015, static

I am trying to set a break point on a static property. I press F5 to start debugging. My breakpoints in main() are tripped, but not the static properties. I know I have done this before with success in VS 2012. Is there an option in VS 2015 that I need to set to be able to debug static properties? My google searches for some reason only turn up results for debugging auto generated methods and properties, but not static ones.

Comment: It works fine, be sure to set the breakpoint on the getter and/or the setter.   Or just plain the "get" or "set" keyword if is an auto-property.  And to install the Updates, VS2015 RTM shipped with a *lot* of debugger bugs.

Comment: @James, if you debug your app using the Step Into, do you get any warning or error messages? I test a simple sample like this one:http://www.dotnetperls.com/static-property , it works well. So you would check that whether it is related to your project or the VS IDE. Since it works well in VS2012, please also compare the settings under TOOLS->Options->Debugging with your VS2015.